# Android SDK built for x86 does not support profile mode?

Tags: flutter, debugging, android-sdk-2.3

it throws this error when I run `--profile`

```
H:\MyApp>flutter run --profile
Profile mode is not supported by Android SDK built for x86.
```

but

```
  H:\MyApp>flutter run --debug
```

works perfectly.

any fixes ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem for `--release` mode but got solved with this:

> If you want to run a release mode APK on an emulator, it needs to be
> one of Flutter's supported ABIs: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, or x86_64.

as seen [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28432#issuecomment-610781427).

As also refered by Flutter docs:

[What are the supported target architectures?](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures)

> When building your application in release mode, Flutter apps can be
> compiled for armeabi-v7a (ARM 32-bit), arm64-v8a (ARM 64-bit), and
> x86-64 (x86 64-bit). Flutter does not currently support building for
> x86 Android.

Answer (score 14):

I got the same issue it got **FIXED 100%**

Basically flutter does not support x86 to run profile
so you need to run it on x64

Follow these steps

1. Download x64 emulator / plug into your latest android mobile which have 64bit architecture
2. Then run this command on terminal flutter run --profile

Then, voila, your app will be install on your device

Comment: in my case, x86_64 emulator doesn't work in profile mode

Comment: This worked perfectly. I created a new VD with x86_64 and it worked. So I was able to debug on my emulator and see the grey screen with errors showing in my android studio terminal.

Answer (score 8):

Run the app on an actual Android device and it will work in profile mode.

Answer (score 6):

AVD settings > Create new Virtual Device > Chose any Device and next > x86 Images Chose look like picture 2 > dowload any version Apı level 29 or 30 recomended

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works! Just need to choose the ABI that have 86 and 64 like you show in the image.

Comment: This answer is the most helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It throws errors as the android emulators does not support --profile and --release mode yet, but if you still want to check it running on laptop then iOS simulators are the other options as it supports both of --release and --profile mode for flutter if you are using it on mac devices. But still iOS is not a option if we are developing the application for android only.

Comment: They do not support profile and release modes either